# Optimising A Date Based Aggregation Query

Tags: mongodb, optimization, aggregation-framework

In my MongoDB instance (3.2), I have various documents representing a website view:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56355620e4b0b1fac0c2d85e"),
  "useragent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1",
  "requestid" : "c99cef30-5650-493a-aa91-7734b0035fb0",
  "sessionid" : "9cad9a9c-5d85-4665-b833-9fc58aeab20b",
  "datetime" : ISODate("2015-11-01T00:00:29.356Z"),
  "ipaddress" : "192.168.1.1",
  "url" : "http://www.somepage.com"
}
```

Now I want to use this information to produce some form of monthly visit reports (so you got 1000 visitors on the 1st, 1500 on the 2nd etc.). So I'm using the following aggregation query:

```
db.data.aggregate([
  { $project: { day: {$dayOfMonth: '$datetime'}, month: {$month: '$datetime'}, year: {$year: '$datetime'} }},
  { $match : { month : 11, year : 2015 }},
  { $group : {
    _id : { month: "$month", day: "$day"},
    count: { $sum : 1 }
  }},
  { $sort : { "_id.day" : 1 }}
]);
```

Works well and takes about a second to run. But now I want to speed it up if possible. So first think I tried was adding an index:

```
db.data.createIndex("datetime": 1);
```

But that actually added 100ms to my query.

So what is the best way to speed up this kind of aggregation (if any)? Can I create indexes on the individual date parts (day, month, year) - my testing says no. Any other ideas?

Comment: The **best** optimization you can do is to remove the `$project` stage at the begining and lead with a `$match` stage instead. Then ( and **only** then ) can the aggregation pipeline use an index to optimise selection. Anything else is altered output that is no longer the "source collection" data, and therefore no index can be applied. A "range" query on the "start" and "end" dates of the month will speed things imensely, as opposed to parsing all the data and creating "calculated fields" for which to later match on. Which of course you do not need. Database basics you should understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have match condition first for queries to work. In your program if you can get startDate, endDate, then first filter the records between those dates. Then try following pipeline, it'll use the index properly.

```
var startDate = new Date('2015-11-01'), endDate = new Date('2015-12-01');

db.data.aggregate([
  {$match: { datetime: {$gt: startDate, $lt: endDate}}},
  { $group : {
    _id : { month: {$month: '$datetime'}, day:{$dayOfMonth: '$datetime'}},
    count: { $sum : 1 }
  }},
  { $sort : { "_id.day" : 1 }}
]);
```

Comment: I voted. But can you please do the OP a favour and also remove the `$project` entirely and just put the "day" and "month" abstraction "directly" into the `$group` `_id`. That is optimal. Though the main point is the preceeding `$match`, a `$project` when you don't need it is also wasting processing time.

Comment: Many thanks to you both. Time to get reading up on my aggregation framework